# Generating ideal step functions using actual step function

Tags: algorithm, math

I plotted a runtime(in seconds) vs input plot for a function as follows:

[image]

You can observe a lot of runtimes which larger than expected represented by the individual points above.

I want to map these points to their expected time downwards to get an ideal step function as follows:

[image]

**RED dots = runtimes which larger than expected**

In the following case the **RED** dots get mapped to respective expected runtimes:

[image]

But it is not always easy to decide where the RED dots should be mapped. For eg:

[image]

In the above case, how will we decide to map the RED dot to runtimes T1 or T2?

Also, there are following cases in which we cannot be sure on how to map the RED dots downwards to their ideal or expected runtimes:

[image]

The blue dots can create noise for mapping the RED dots downwards in case if we decide to map the dots by judging the neighbours

Finally, there can be a lot of noise as in the following Case:

[image]

So, the aim is to achieve an ideal step function to the best possible accuracy by mapping the RED dots downwards to their ideal expected runtimes

Will be thankful for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If the runtime is really linear like the plot tells us.*

You can create a linear regression over your data, it will fit the main line of dots without the dots with runtime larger than expected. Than for all the other dots you can take the `x` value and fit it over the regression, than round it up or down based on if the number modulo 1 is greater than 0.5 or not.

In the first case (practical scenario) you do not have to use this but it will still work since the regression should pass through the middle of all the horizontal lines. This method is very useful in case 4 since it is ignoring the nearby points.

Tip:
While creating the linear regression try to develop a method to ignore the outliers in order to achieve a "clean" regression.

Edit:
More explanation
[image]

The red line is the output of the linear regression, now for each point take its light blue line and find the intersection point. Now for that intersection point round it up or down (depending on which one is closer) to the T level that match.

Comment: Yonlif, can you kindly explain this in depth with an example as I am finding it a little tough to what you are saying

Comment: Added an example :)

Comment: I appreciate your efforts. Correct me if I got you correct. So, 1st we need to ignore all the outliers. Then fit the graph into a regression such that the line passes through the centres of all the horizontal bars (as this will eliminate the errors caused due to noise) and finally try to find the T values using regression line and assign the T value which is closest to the regression value?

Comment: Yes, I think you understood me very well :), if you are pleased from the answer you can approve it.

Comment: I have some more doubts. In this case we are sure that when the step function breaks (or starts taking news values), we have noise. So, should we consider this noisy data in our training dataset or exclude it and why?

Comment: I think you should exclude everything which is very far from the step function, maybe using LOF or Mahalanobis distance (or any anomaly detection algorithm), but this is only if you have time. Linear regression is quite robust and should produce a good regression even if you are keeping all of the points since it is trying to fit most of the points and most of them are on the step function.

Comment: Could you share the origin of the data?

Comment: Hi Yonlif, Kindly take a note of origin of the data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60925228/why-actual-runtime-for-a-larger-search-value-is-smaller-than-a-lower-search-valu